# Elastic search match_phrase_prefix not able to find all records

Tags: database, search, elasticsearch

We are using elastic search 1.1.0. We are trying to query an index with match_phrase_prefix as following:

```
{
    "query":{
      "match_phrase_prefix" : {
        "name" : {
          "query" : "Harry Joy"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

We have 4 records named Harry Joy. Above query works perfectly if we write full name, but if we write first name and first char of last name it returns only 1 records instead of 4.

Following query returns only 1 record:

```
{
    "query":{
      "match_phrase_prefix" : {
        "name" : {
          "query" : "Harry J"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

But following query returns all 4 records:

```
{
    "query":{
      "match_phrase_prefix" : {
        "name" : {
          "query" : "Harry Jo"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

We need to able to search all 4 with single char in second word as well. What can we do here to make it work and what is the reason behind not searching with only 1 char and works with 2 chars in second word?

This is how I created my index:

```
{
    "river": "users", 
    "data": {
        "type": "mongodb", 
        "mongodb": { 
           "servers": [
                   { "host": "localhost", "port": 27017 }
             ],
            "db": "mydb", 
            "collection": "users", 
            "gridfs": false
        }, 
        "index": { 
            "name": "susers", 
            "type": "users" 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Harry J' returns 4 results for me. What is the mapping for the `name` property?

Comment: @DanTuffery what do you mean by mapping? if you mean how index is created than I updated my question.

Comment: Does 'users' have a schema (mapping)? I think Dan wants to know more about the name field. What analyzers are used, etc.

Comment: @coffeeaddict no it doesn't have any field mapping.

Comment: @coffeeaddict I also tried adding mapping as Dan suggested in his answer(currently deletedby him) to make a separate filed untouched as not analyzed and search on that. But in that I lose the functionality of case insensitivity. I have to write in perfect case as in the field.

Answer (score 0):

for match_phrase_prefix the default of max_expansions is 50.
it means that for term **"Harry J"** elastic will look up for **"J"** in sorted term dictionary for first 50 terms. it will combine the term into query ( eg: "Jane", "Joy", "Joke" ) using lexicographic order up to 50 ( max_expansions ).

( this is the reason why you find all 4 records when you term is **"Harry Jo"** because it much easier to find **"Jo"** in the sorted term dictionary for first 50 terms ).

you can increase max_expansions by using query like this:
(using large amount of max_expansions can decrease performance )

```
{
"query":{
  "match_phrase_prefix" : {
    "name" : {
      "query" : "Harry J",
      "max_expansions" : 100
    }
  }
}
}
```

more info you can find here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html#query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix